# Docker Compose Volumes Basics

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I understand if it was:

```
volumes:
  - /home/{user}/config:/config
```

You would find it in the local user directory -> /home/{user}/config

But when declaring;

```
volumes:
  - ./:/config
```

Where is "./"?

Answer (score 0):

`.` in Unix generally means "the current directory", and in the case of Compose it's [the directory containing the (first) `docker-compose.yml` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understanding-multiple-compose-files).

Comment: Thanks, If I am using it in a Portainer Stack instead of Docker Compose where would the "current directory" be?